# Linux and SPDIF output - crackling/distortion on 44.1 kHz

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

For over a decade now, when I use an SPDIF output on Linux, there is always crackling and bad sound if the 44.1 kHz frequency is used. It was ALSA in 2006, it is PulseAUdio now, but the issue persists.

Pinning the frequency to 48 kHz fixed the issue. However, music typically comes in 44.1 kHz, so a 48 kHz output means resampling every time.

The issue is well known, for example, in [PulseAudio/Troubleshooting - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting) look for "choppy".

So is there any way to make Linux do the 44.1 kHz rate properly?

(I don't have a 24 bit capable SPDIF controller, so it was all 16 bit. I did try 96 kHz but got nothing better at all, just some hissing noise for some reason)

Comment: In my case this solved the problem: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Choppy/distorted_sound

Answer (score 1):

Guess:

Your SPDIF hardware only has 48 kHz in hardware (it's the default for most SPDIF hardware), and when you set it to 44.1 kHz, resampling happens in some place that's vulnerable to underflow, and hence the crackling/distortion.

OTOH, with 48 kHz and, say, Pulseaudio, Pulseaudio will do the resampling, and apparently with a large enough buffer that underflow is not an issue.

To confirm if this guess is right, one would have to look at the details of your hardware, and how you have configured everything.

Comment: Thank you !  What solved the problem was setting `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` to 

`avoid-resampling = yes`
`default-sample-rate = 48000`

Found it here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Choppy/distorted_sound